# Regression table using Knitr and stargazer

Tags: r, latex, regression, knitr

I am trying to use knitr and stargazer to export a regression table from R to Latex. Unfortunately I get the following error message   *"Missing $ inserted"  I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.*
  Do I miss anything in my code or might this be an error from the stargazer package?
Any hints on how one can use knitr and stargazer together?

```
\documentclass{article}   
\begin{document}   
%Load dataset and run regression    

 << lm, echo=FALSE >>=  
load('dataset.RData')  
library(stargazer)  
lm1 <- lm(y~ x ,data=dataset)  
@


<< table_texstyle, echo=FALSE, comment=NA, results='asis' >>=  
stargazer(lm1)  
@  
\end{document}
```

Comment: might want to try `xtable` if you can't get that working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works well for me under Ubuntu 12.04, TeXLive 2012 and R 2.15.2.

```
\documentclass{article}   
\begin{document}   
<<lm, echo=FALSE >>=  
df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=rnorm(10))
library(stargazer)  
lm1 <- lm(y ~ x ,data=df)  
@

<<table_texstyle, echo=FALSE, results='asis' >>=  
stargazer(lm1)  
@  
\end{document}
```

You did not tell us what is `dataset` (we have no idea of your `dataset.RData`), so we cannot really know what could be the reason of the failure. At least you need to paste the tex output like

```
% Table created by StarGazer v.1.0 by Marek Hlavac, Harvard University. E-mail: mhlavac at alumni.princeton.edu
% Date and time: Wed, Nov 14, 2012 - 06:20:12 PM
\begin{table}[htb] \centering 

....

\end{table}
```

so we know if the problem came from LaTeX.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As your example worked well on my computer I tried to figure out the difference with my dataset. The problem in my case was that one independent variable was called x_z and the _ causes the error message.

Comment: @Tom then you need to read the documentation of `stargazer` more carefully to figure out it is possible to escape `_`, or use alternative labels for these otherwise problematic labels.

Comment: Yes, I just used an alternative label to solve this problem. Many thanks.

Answer (score 8):

stargazer v.2.0 is now out on CRAN, and should be able to deal with variable names that include dollar signs and underscore without any trouble. Try installing the new version, and running your code again - you should not have any problems.

Comment: in version 4.0, use stargazer(...,header=FALSE, type='latex' )to suppress the header so that the conversion to Latex won't report error.